# Is it possible to downgrade an Entity Framework Core code-first migration without the migration present in the code base?

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration

Imagine a micro services architecture using EF Core code first with migrations.

A kubernetes init container will migrate the SQL Server database before running the actual application container.

But sometimes we rollback to a previous version of the application.
This means the database is in an invalid and possibly incompatible state.

I would like to migrate the database back to the most recent migration present in the code base of that version, but the `down` migration won't be know.

Is it possible at all to facilitate this? I guess the database itself needs knowledge about the way to migrate back, but is it possible?

I did some research but it seems to me this scenario is unsupported at the time of writing.

Comment: When you add migrations via EF and you stick to code-first, you get both the up and down migrations.  Why are you saying it won't be "known"?  If you ignore those for now, are you asking if the database itself has a way to go "back"?  In pretty much any scenario someone needs to write the reverse.  I would also be *extremely* skeptical of anything other than EF rolling back and even then you have a potential for data loss.

Comment: Yeah I mean application version 2 has a migration, with Up and Down methods ofcourse.
Then when you rollback to version 1, the database will still be on 'version 2'. But because version 1 is running code-wise, it doesn't know anything about the migration and how to roll it back.
I would like to be able to rollback to database version 1 as well, data loss won't be an issue.